# WS02 BAM - Gadget Generation Tool

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

I followed the [tutorial](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM200/Gadget+Generation+Tool) to create Simple Gadgets in WSO2 BAM Version 2.0.1. In this version as shown in tutorial I could see

1.Bar graph

2.Table is supported by Gadget generation Tool.

Just wanted to know other charts like Pie Charts,Histogram ,etc are supported by Gadget Generation Tool.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment only Bar chart and Table is supported in the Gadget Generation tool. But you can  create your own [BAM dashboard](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM200/BAM+Dashboard) with all the UI components you like. Bug fixed version of BAM dashboard is available from BAM 2.0.1. You can try on it too.